# how to delete cardview in a recycler view and its json data

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I want to delete card in a `RecyclerView` after selecting it.data in the `RecyclerView` is JSON data

```
public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                    JsonObject responseObject = response.body();
                    if (responseObject.has("data")) {
                        JsonArray arrayobject = responseObject.getAsJsonArray("data");
                        ArrayList<User_Details_Model> myorder = getGeneral(arrayobject.toString());
                        viewRequestControllerCallback.hitsuccess1(myorder);
```

Comment: Hello, @Shaheer Kp you want to remove a record from the list recycler view after select it am I, right?

Comment: have you resolved your problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

**this is the adapter**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserViewHolder holder, final int 
position) {
  final User_Details_Model product = user_details.get(position);

  Log.d("######",user_details.toString());
  holder.tv1.setText(product.getDriverId());
  holder.tv2.setText(product.getDriverName());
  holder.tv3.setText(product.getVehicleId());
  holder.tv4.setText(product.getVehicleType());
  holder.tv5.setText(product.getOilType());

 holder.button_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    int pos=holder.getAdapterPosition();
    if (position==pos){
      getdetails();
      user_details.remove(pos);

     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good resource to detect which cardView is clicked. After clicking a cardView you can delete it:

[Recyclerview-listener](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(ContentItem item);
}

public void bind(final ContentItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
    ...
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Will get item and then delete from `List` and then call `notifydatasetchanged()`

Comment: You have to implement an interface in your class using the adapter and inside override method, you just got the selected item and from that item, you just have to remove that selected item from a position.